# Bk ground check under review

Tags: background-check

I just got offered a job pending a background check. I called today to check up on things and was told it was sent to corporate for review. I had a cop run my state ID a couple weeks ago and he told the dispatcher I may have a 21/(suspended license) out in MI which I no longer live for years.

My question is would a warrant for a suspended driver's license disqualify a background check if its from a different state

Comment: Yes, but its in another state and its been almost 5 years. Also, I've had plenties of jobs where I am now. This is the first time this has ever happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different companies have different policies. From my experience, what responsibilities that position has also plays a factor.

For example, if you were applying for the position of a truck driver, then having a DUI will probably prevent you from getting that job, but might be OK if you were applying for the job of a cashier.

EDIT: If you have a warrant out for your arrest, you should probably get that resolved...

Comment: Would it go up for review, if so why? Its a warrant for it in MI, but I've been here four years and never had this problem with jobs.

Comment: I used to run background checks for prospective applicants and the company we used would search the entire US for the applicant to see if they have a record of some sort. Again, it's dependent on company policy. If you haven't had an issue, no need to really worry about it now.

Comment: Having a suspended license in another state is something you should resolve, and if you have an arrest warrant, that's a big deal.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, that is true. Misread that part of it. Will update.

Comment: If the job involves travel, a warrant would probably be a big deal. It would be embarrassing to the company to send someone for a meeting with a customer and have the employee arrested in front of the customer.